# [disabled]="ChooseButton" making all buttons disabled

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an *ngFor which gives me the certain item list of goods and I click a particular button to choose them. As I click my choose button, it temporarily disables the button till the time I get response from my back-end. As I get my response from back-end, the button becomes active to un-choose the item.

The issue I am facing here is, as I click the choose button, it makes all buttons of the list temporarily disabled. But what I want is to make only the clicked button disabled.

My HTML code snippet:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let list of list_Array;>  
 <ion-card-content >
        <p style="color: #666; " [innerHTML]="list.item"></p>
      </ion-card-content>  
    <button ion-button color="secondary" clear (click)="activeButton(list._id)" *ngIf="list.isAlreadyChosen==true" [disabled]="ChooseButton">
              <div class="chosen" 
                    ng-class="{'chosen': isChosen}">
                  <p >choose</p>
              </div>
      </button>
     <button ion-button color="secondary" clear (click)="activeButton(list._id)" *ngIf="list.isAlreadyChosen==false"  [disabled]="ChooseButton" >
              <div class="choosen" 
                    ng-class="{'chosen': isChosen}">
                  <p >choose</p>
              </div>
      </button>
    </ion-card>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently you have `ChooseButton` flag global, that's why as soon as you change that flag, it reflects everywhere in component context.

Make the `ChooseButton` property local to each collection element i.e. `list.ChooseButton`.

```
[disabled]="list.ChooseButton"
```

For applying the above you should change the `activeButton` function to below, before that pass `list` object on `click` of button like `(click)="activeButton(list)"`

**Function**

```
activeButton (item) { 
    item.ChooseButton = true;
    console.log("listId", item._id);
}
```

Comment: then how may i make it true or false in my type script file , 
 Currently i am using it like 
activeButton = function (listId) {
 this.ChooseButton = true;
 and after i have my api call response i make it 
this.ChooseButton=false
}

Comment: it's giving me an error like 'Cannot create property 'ChooseButton' on string '58bfc0e3733305f5e' '
this string is the ID of the chosen item

Comment: @devanshsadhotraYou have to pass object on (click)="activeButton(list)", not string.

Comment: You can use a for loop after the list_Array is loaded and create `chooseButton` property on each of them. Will add another answer for this.

Comment: @SagarKulkarni yes , your solution worked but it increases time complexity from the app end.

Comment: @devanshsadhotra Look at the 2nd answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1:**
As @Pankaj Parkar's answer said - Each item in your `list_Array` needs to have it's own flag `chooseButton`, than having 1 common flag for all items to make only the clicked button disabled.

Now, say you have loaded your `list_Array`. You can use following for loop to add this property to it and set it to false initially:

```
for(var i = 0; i < list_Array.length; i++){
    list_Array[i]['chooseButton'] = false;
}
```

Now, pass the list as parameter from your UI code to `activeButton(list)` method like : `(click)="activeButton(list)"` (Remember to pass an entire object here than `list._id` as you have done).

Now, in your method:

```
activeButton(list) { 
    list.chooseButton = !list.chooseButton;
}
```

Here, I have negated `list.chooseButton` to it's previous value (true -> false or false -> true). Hope this helps.

**Answer 2:**
You already have `list.isAlreadyChosen` present in your `list_Array`.
Just do `[disabled]="!list.isAlreadyChosen"` in first button and `[disabled]="list.isAlreadyChosen"` in second should solve your problem. Easy. ;)

Comment: Please look at 2nd answer. ;)

Comment: as i followed your second answer it made the already chosen button disabled and unchosen button enabled . but the functionality should remain like i can also unchose the already chosen item

Comment: I just edited again to reverse the `list.isAlreadyChosen` flag to `!list.isAlreadyChosen` in first button and vice-versa. Is this what you want? Basically, what I am saying here is to manipulate `list.isAlreadyChosen` variable than creating another.

Comment: just like we have like functionality on facebook , firstly u can like the pic and then u can remove the like. that's the exact way i wanted. it was working that way , but in your second answer it gets stuck once i have marked it chosen/unchosen. but way suggested by pankaj it works as desired. 

 Thanks to you for the valueable answer ,I will use it in some other module as it was required by me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to achieve this:

```
//component
disableMe:boolean[];

disableThis(id){
   this.disableMe[id] = !this.disableMe[id];
}

//template
<button ion-button color="secondary" clear (click)="activeButton(list._id); disableThis(list._id)" *ngIf="list.isAlreadyChosen==true" [disabled]="disableMe[list._id]">
              <div class="chosen" 
                    ng-class="{'chosen': isChosen}">
                  <p >choose</p>
              </div>
</button>
```